# Does the order of condition matter in Having clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL, I wonder does the order of conditions in a HAVING clause matter if I use both WHERE and HAVING clauses in my query. For example, for the following queries(taking out from a book), are they exactly the same? My understanding is HAVING is applied to GROUP data, which have already been filtered by the WHERE clause, then SUM() function will only applied to those filtered data. However in the second query, a WHERE clause wasn't applied beforehand, and the condition InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31' is applied at the end of the HAVING Clause, so SUM() will calculate from all data, which is different from the first query. Am I understand it right?

```
-- First Query
SELECT
    InvoiceDate, 
    COUNT(*) AS InvoiceQty,
    SUM(InvoiceTotal) AS InvoiceSum
FROM
    Invoices
WHERE 
    InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'
GROUP BY
    InvoiceDate
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
        AND SUM(InvoiceTotal) > 100
ORDER BY
    InvoiceDate DESC;

-- Second Query 
SELECT
    InvoiceDate, 
    COUNT(*) AS InvoiceQty,
    SUM(InvoiceTotal) AS InvoiceSum
FROM
    Invoices 
GROUP BY
    InvoiceDate
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
        AND SUM(InvoiceTotal) > 100
        AND InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'
ORDER BY
    InvoiceDate DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The order should not matter in the `HAVING` clause.  Most of the work is being done by the `GROUP BY` anyway.  There could be a difference if one of the clauses is much more expensive to check (say, because of the use of a user-defined function).  Your query doesn't have such a condition, though.

On the other hand, the difference between conditions in the `HAVING` and the `WHERE` clause are important.  And, you can rewrite the second query as:

```
SELECT InvoiceDate, COUNT(*) AS InvoiceQty,
       SUM(InvoiceTotal) AS InvoiceSum
FROM Invoices
WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31' 
GROUP BY InvoiceDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(InvoiceTotal) > 100
ORDER BY InvoiceDate DESC;
```

Filtering *before* the `GROUP BY` is usually more efficient, because it reduces the amount of data needed to process the aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding order, for a SELECT statement in SQL Server database. This order determines when the objects defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent steps.

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

Since now you know the order, you can find out how the processing will be. Refer to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) for more insight.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming correctly. The two queries have equal results, but the first query should usually be qicker, because as you say it dismisses unwanted data right away instead of doing all calculations on it before dismissing it.

If the database system has a good query optimizer, it may notice that part of the `HAVING` clause in the second query can be moved to `WHERE` and may internally re-write the query, so you'd end up with query #1 in both cases. But you should not rely on that. Write your queries as good as possible, i.e. use query #1.